# Remove subdomain ONLY from url

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, url

How can I strip a form input URL of its subdomain and the subdomain only?

See [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oh88a1v/) or below code for example.

```
  $('[type="button"]').click(function() {
var btn = document.getElementById("download"); //get the button
var input = $('#soundcloud-url').val();

if (input.startsWith("https://soundcloud.com/") || input.startsWith("https://m.soundcloud.com/")) {
  btn.style.display = "inline-block"; //show the button
} else {
  btn.style.display = "none"; //hide the button
  alert('Enter a valid Souncloud url');
}
$('#soundcloud-iframe').attr('src', '//w.soundcloud.com/player/?' + $('form').serialize());
return false;
```

What I basically need is, if someone enters an url in the form from the mobile Soundcloud website, http://m.souncloud..., the URL converts to the normal URL automatically: without the ".m" part... But if someone enters the normal URL (non-mobile), nothing should happen.

Should be an easy fix but I cant figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out the `m.` subdomain with a JS `replace` like this:

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  var input = $('#soundcloud-url').val().replace('//m.', '//');
  console.log('stripped input:', input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

URL: <input id="soundcloud-url" value="https://m.soundcloud.com/neilcic/no-credit-card" />

<button id="submit">GO</button>
```

Comment: But "url2" is not defined beforehand, it is set by the form input. Can you show me how to implement this in my example code?

Comment: Just use your `input` var instead of my `url1`/`url2` variables. Those are just to demonstrate how the replacement works.

Comment: @AffiLead I've updated my example. Hope this makes it easier to understand!

Comment: I tried implementing `.replace('//m.', '//')` in my own script but it doesnt work..

Comment: What am I doing wrong? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/79mkct3o/)  Forgive my noobyness